# How select one row from two distinct column with same value

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

[image]

Hi i need select only a row.. for this table

row1 = revserse (row4)

my code:

```
    select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() ID, c.localidad, acalle,bcalle
    from (
      SELECT a.localidad, a.calle acalle, b.calle bcalle
      FROM (
        SELECT LOCALIDAD, CALLE 
        FROM TEST.INICIAL
        WHERE CALLE IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY 1,2
      ) A
      INNER JOIN (
        SELECT LOCALIDAD, CALLE 
        FROM TEST.INICIAL
        WHERE CALLE IS NOT NULL
        GROUP BY 1,2
      ) B ON A.LOCALIDAD = B.LOCALIDAD 
      WHERE SIMILARITY(A.CALLE ,B.CALLE) > 0.45
         AND A.CALLE <> B.CALLE
    ) c
    where acalle not like '%NORTE' 
      and acalle not like '%SUR' 
      and acalle not like '%ESTE' 
      and acalle not like '%OESTE' 
      AND Bcalle not like '%NORTE' 
      and Bcalle not like '%SUR' 
      and Bcalle not like '%ESTE' 
      and Bcalle not like '%OESTE' 
      AND ACALLE NOT LIKE 'PJE%' 
      AND BCALLE NOT LIKE 'PJE%'
      and acalle not like '%BIS'
      and bcalle not like '%BIS' 
      and acalle not like '%CALLE%' 
      AND BCALLE NOT LIKE '%CALLE%'
    order by 1,2,3
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: this indentation is interesting -- specifically designed to make it less clear where the joins are I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `CASE` to make sure the column values are in the same order (doesn't matter how they're ordered, just that it's consistent from one row to the next), build an array of `[col1, col2]`, and `SELECT DISTINCT` on that.

```
testdb=# with orig_output as (
select 1::bigint as id, 'ADROGUE' as localidad, 'JORGE' as acalle, 'JORGE DE KAY' as bcalle UNION ALL
select 2, 'ADROGUE', 'PLAZA ESTABAN ADROGUE', 'ESTEBAN ADROGUE' UNION ALL
select 3, 'ADROGUE', 'ESTEBAN ADROGUE', 'PLAZA ESTABAN ADROGUE' UNION ALL
select 4, 'ADROGUE', 'JORGE DE KAY', 'JORGE'),
make_columns_be_in_same_order AS (
SELECT id, localidad, acalle, bcalle,
  CASE WHEN acalle>bcalle
    THEN ARRAY[acalle, bcalle]
    ELSE ARRAY[bcalle, acalle]
  END AS acalle_and_bcalle
FROM orig_output
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (acalle_and_bcalle)
id, localidad, acalle, bcalle
FROM make_columns_be_in_same_order;
 id | localidad |        acalle         |     bcalle      
----+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------
  1 | ADROGUE   | JORGE                 | JORGE DE KAY
  2 | ADROGUE   | PLAZA ESTABAN ADROGUE | ESTEBAN ADROGUE
(2 rows)
```